# Why is AutoLayout ignoring some Contraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

The app has a simple TableView Controller that displays images on the left side. (see the first picture). The `UIView` is aligned to the x-axis, has a leading space constraint, and has a max width. I'd have thought this too be enough to prevent the image from being distorted past 130 pixels, but it is not. When the device is in landscape mode, the issue is more obvious.

Why are the some of the constraints being ignored (see how some of the constraints are greyed out in the view debugger screenshot), and more importantly, how can I have variable width images with a fixed height not appear distorted in the cell?

[image: Autolayout all blue and not complaining]

[image: some of the constraints are being greyed out]

[image: in landscape mode the problem is more clearly visible.]

Comment: The kind of images you have will distort with width change set for the images. if you really want to have variable width you need to have the height variable too for image, or you have another option of using `AspectFill content mode`. Else just fix the width no variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked two questions which I will answer seperately:

1. **Why are the some of the constraints being ignored:**

> They aren't being ignored actually. You have not set any constraints for those specific areas. When you apply a constraint, a respective line is highlighted in blue. When you haven't applied a constraint for a specific side, it remains grey.

2. **How can I have variable width images with a fixed height not appear distorted in the cell?**

> You can use either AspectFit or AspectFill, so that the aspect ratio of your images is not disturbed and they don't looks stretched.
>
> You should also remove the width constraint from the ImageView. Then you can use AspectFill if you know that your height will not increase from 130. If your image height can be more than 130, you should rather use AspectFit.

Comment: Two of the vertical lines and one of the horizontal lines are greyed out. Does that means those constraints are not set? Also, how do you interpret that grid of blue and grey lines? As in, which lines correspond to which constraints so that you can go about systematically changing the grey lines to blue lines?

Comment: The two inner most lines, bisecting the rectangle show centre horizontally and centre vertically.
The fours lines that make the rectangle, show leading space, trailing space, top space, and bottom space to parent view.
The two lines outside the rectangle show constant width (the horizontal line at the extreme bottom) and constant height (the vertical line at the extreme left).

Answer (score 0):

You have constraints that are contradictory. You set the leading space to superview and you constrain the image's centerX to the superview's centerX (with a constant offset). Those two are enough to dictate a width. As the superview gets wider, its center moves further from its leading edge. Therefore, the image view's center does, too. Since the image view's leading edge is anchored, moving its center further away has the effect of increasing its width.

This will conflict with your explicit width constraint.

I would expect that the unsatisfiable constraints would be logged.

You need to figure out how you want that conflict resolved. You can lower the priority of one of those constraints. You can simply get rid of the centerX constraint. Or whatever you decide.

Comment: Wouldn't XCode show the constraints in red if they are contradictory, instead of in blue?

Comment: Only if they were actually contradicting in the layout on the canvas. Xcode doesn't call out *potentially* contradictory constraints.